# Handling an Activity when non JSON data/Empty data is recieved with Alert or Custom Message

Tags: android, json

I followed [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm) to Read JSON data in android

over there I am passing result data to another activity

```
public class MainAct1 extends Activity {

private static String urlString;

private static final String My_TAG= "Log Status";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.data);

    if(Dcon.isInternetAvailable(this))
    {
        try {
            urlString = "https://example.net/api_json";
            new ProcessJSON(this).execute();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainAct1.this);
            builder.setMessage("Note: Your Server ID is Invalid \n Please check the Server Status");
            builder.setTitle("Please Check Server Details");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK",null);

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainAct1.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Connection Error !");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Internet not available, Check your internet connectivity and try again");

        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(1);
                finish();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}

private class ProcessJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public Context context;
    String FinalJSonResult;

    public ProcessJSON(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler(urlString);

        try {
            sh.ExecutePostRequest();
            if (sh.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                FinalJSonResult = sh.getResponse();
                if (FinalJSonResult != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject JObject = new JSONObject(FinalJSonResult);
                        JSONObject response = JObject.getJSONObject("response");

                     if(response.has("status")) {

                        String status = response.getString("status");
                            MainAct1.this.finish();
                            Intent op = new Intent(MainAct1.this, MainRes1.class);
                            op.putExtra("mydata", status);
                            op.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                            op.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            op.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            op.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                            startActivity(op);
                        }
                        else {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "No JSON data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(NSdata.this).create();
                                alertDialog.setTitle("Server Error !");
                                alertDialog.setMessage("No Data Received");
                                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                                        System.exit(1);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });
                                alertDialog.show();
                            }
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainAct1.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Note: Your Server ID is Invalid \n Please check the Server Status");
                        builder.setTitle("Please Check Server Details");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK",null);

                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {

                    }
                }
                else{
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainAct1.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("User Error !");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("No Data Received");
                    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                            System.exit(1);
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(context, sh.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(false);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please wait for a While.. Don't Go back .!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

this is my JSON Data

`{"response":{"status":"Active"}}`

or

`{"response":{"status":"Active:4 in stock"}}`

So now I am facing issue with

**1.NonJSON** some times json data is not received due to server error

or it will show Just some HTML headings...

I need to  data Handle it Can any one suggest me.. on this kind

and

**2.Empty JSON Data** Some times Result may be Null like

`{"response":{"status":""}}`

or

`{"response":{}}`

Can Any Suggest me How to Handle those Kinds I already Given Alerts But its not working.

Now I am handling these two kinds of data but Some times I am getting Empty

**Update**

For a valid JSON data Its Showing Result in next Activity/page in a Text View...

Valid JSON data `{"response":{"status":"Active"}}` or  `{"response":{"status":"Please set the data."}}`

I am showing Result... in Next Page

But Sometimes I will get Invalid JSON data like `{"response":{"status":}}` or Just HTML page with Welcome text... or OOps page not found ...

So I want to Handle them,,, if I get Invalid JSON Data I want to SHOW the Alert to the USER.... so that's what I am trying But its not working 
Please Help me on this types

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, your issue is only "alert is not displaying"?

Comment: not Only Alerts I want to Handle those conditions..

Comment: What are this conditions? As per my understanding you are able to parse data. Please let me  know if I am missing something

Comment: Actually if there is a valid JSON data it will work fine like `{"response":{"status":"Active"}}` or `{"response":{"status":"Active:4 in stock"}}`... But Some time I will get Non data like `Oops not found` or `Server Error` or Empty JSON data like  `{"response":{"status":""}}` or `{"response":{}}`... I need to Handle those Conditions...

Comment: did you try shifting your alert dialog code to `onPostExecute` method rather than calling `sh.ExecutePostRequest();` ?

Comment: Yes I have Added I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49423073/8039571) answer.. but for correct one also I am getting Alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONObject JObject = new JSONObject(FinalJSonResult); 
JSONObject response = JObject.getJSONObject("response");  

       // Check Key found or Not
    if(response.has("status")) {

                String status = response.getString("status");

                   // Check if Status Empty or Not
                   if(status.isEmpty()){

                   }

     } else {
            //Status Key not found
     }
```

- `DoInBackground()` only gets executed on a different thread other than the main UI thread.
- So you need to write AlertDialog in `onPostExecute`.
- In `ProcessJSON` class use `FinalJSonResult` string to handle different situation in onPostExecute().

> **ProcessJSON** Class

```
private class ProcessJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public Context context;
    String FinalJSonResult;

    public ProcessJSON(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        FinalJSonResult = "";
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler(urlString);

        try {
            sh.ExecutePostRequest();
            if (sh.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                FinalJSonResult = sh.getResponse();
                if (FinalJSonResult != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject JObject = new JSONObject(FinalJSonResult);
                        JSONObject response = JObject.getJSONObject("response");

                        if(response.has("status")) {

                            String status = response.getString("status");
                            MainAct1.this.finish();
                            Intent op = new Intent(MainAct1.this, MainRes1.class);
                            op.putExtra("mydata", status);
                            op.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                            op.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            op.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            op.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                            startActivity(op);
                        }
                        else {
                            FinalJSonResult = "No JSON data";
                        }
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {

                        FinalJSonResult = "Your Server ID is Invalid";

                    }

                }
                else{

                    FinalJSonResult = "User Error";

                }
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(context, sh.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        if(FinalJSonResult.equalsIgnoreCase("No JSON data")){

            // Your AlertDialog code....

        }else if(FinalJSonResult.equalsIgnoreCase("Your Server ID is Invalid")){

            // Your AlertDialog code....

        }else if(FinalJSonResult.equalsIgnoreCase("User Error")){

            // Your AlertDialog code....

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I have Given this in  `else { Toast.makeText(context, "No JSON data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }` but its not working

Comment: try to set Log instead of Toast like : Log.v("response..", "..No JSON data..");

Comment: I used your Log.. When JSON is empty like `{"response":{""}}` It will shows log at `catch (JSONException e) {` But I want to Show a Alert .... But If I give alert Its showing this exception `W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` at Alert... that log is fine but I want to add Alert...

Comment: DoInBackground() only gets executed on a different thread other than the main UI thread. So AlertDialog not work in that thread. Use onPostExecute method to show AlertDialog.

Comment: could you suggest me with your Updated Answer .. Please check my updated Code of that Activity.. In next Activity I will Just Display Result...

Comment: Still Same nothing Happen When Data is `{"response":{}}` or HTML... And I am facing same error at `catch (JSONException e) { ............ AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();dialog.show();}` ....this is error `W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Comment: remove all AlertDialog code from DoInBackground() .... try to put Log in onPostExecute()  and print FinalJSonResult...

Comment: Actually I duplicated my Code with and added your code in duplicate class but forgot to add in Manifest... Here Alerts worked ..But Now for Correct also same alert is coming... only this part is always showing .... `else if(FinalJSonResult.equalsIgnoreCase("Your Server ID is Invalid")){

            // Your AlertDialog code....

        }`  even is it correct or incorrect JSON data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167779/discussion-between-nikunj-and-ravi).

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
if(response.has("status")) {
        // Key found in Response JsonObject
        String status = response.getString("status");
    } else {
        //Status Key not found in Response JsonObject
    }
```

Comment: I have Given this in else `{ Toast.makeText(context, "No JSON data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }` and I tried with Alert  but its not working

Comment: its not working only in that case in which response jsonobject not containing status tag.

Comment: If you handle the server error then you can use retrofit in which onError() method will handle the server error.

Comment: Please update your code..I want to check what are you doing??

Answer (score 1):

I recommend use library like Gson. and through try/catch & JsonSyntaxException will validate data. 
but original reason of bug is shape of data. 
rewrite shape of json data in serverside.

Comment: its just a one or few lines data.. So I am not Using any other libraries...

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask has 4 methods i.e. onPreExecute(), doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...), onPostExecute(Result).

doInBackground() method is used to execute the task in the background. For any update on UI we use onPostExecute() method, but if you want to update the UI from doInBackground() than please **try this**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(<your class name>.this, "Your message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  // or you can use your alert dialog here
   }
});
```

For **JSON** you can try below code:

```
 if (sh.getResponseCode() == 200) {
     if(response.has("status")) {
          if (!response.isNull("status")){
            String status = response.getString("status");
           }else{
            //Your alert/toast by using  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {...}
           }
     }else{
        //Your alert/toast by using  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {...}
     }
  }else{
    //Your alert/toast by using  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {...}
  }
```

I hope this code will help you

Comment: mostly this is final i think it solved up to 40% of my issue

Answer (score 1):

You need add “return Code” in your jsonData.  Then you judge if HTTP Status Code equal "200"  and “return code” equal "success code"

Answer (score 0):

Use isNull method to check weather json key/value is null or not.Add a try catch block to handle unknown data. You can try below code to achieve this.

```
try{
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(RESPONSE_STRING);
     JSONObject subJson = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
     if (subJson.isNull("status")) {

       /*Do you work*/

     }
   } catch (JSONException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.something_wrong), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Same way you check for "response" as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface with two functions named 'onSuccessJson(Json json)' and 'onFailure(String error)' and while getting the response check if its json or html like the above code, and pass the respective data to the interface functions. You will get the response where the function is implemented. On 'onFailure(String error)' call the alert dialog, or if success response the call will occur on 'onSuccess(Json json)' you can do further. AsyncTask works like thread, don't call the context related thing in 'doInBackground'